# Corrupted CSS File

Tags: css, file-recovery

Recently today, the power went out unexpectedly while i was editing one of my css files.
after the power came back, i rushed to check if the file was ok but it wasn't :(
it was corrupted, when opened in notepad it shows empty characters file size was not zero.

when i checked it in Komodo IDE, which i was using before the power shortage it was showing something weird i don't know how to describe it right, so i'm posting an image:

[image]

I wanted to know if there is any way i could recover my file :(

Comment: @ do you have one more copy in the source safe?? or in production

Comment: Well, you're pretty f*cked up, it looks like your file is overwritten with NULL bytes. You could try recovery software like Recuva to get the deleted file back.

Comment: one more idea open the css in browser like firefox and see how the output is and probably you can save from there

Comment: @Zubair1 What is the size of the file?

Comment: you don't do version control?  using SVN, Git, or Mercurial...  some editor I know save a backup copy of the file... not sure about yours...

Comment: The filesize of the css file is: 44kb

Comment: i do have an old copy of this file which is about 3 days old, and will miss out alot of the changes i made in the past 3 days.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: already tried recuva but it wasn't useful.

Comment: @gov: when i tried viewing the file in the browser it showed nothing purely empty.

Comment: @Zubair1, you're going to spend more time trying to recover the file than you would recreating it from your 3 day old backup. You've done it once so this time it will be faster. Now, go get mozy or dropbox and start using git or mercurial so that if this happens again you don't even sweat it.

Comment: can someone provide me with a noobish tutorial about these version control systems :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to recover from your disaster is to restore from a backup.  You will have to recreate all of the work you did since that backup.  Sorry.

Many of the comments have mentioned using a version control system as a way to mitigate risks like corrupted files.  You asked for a tutorial on version control systems.  Mercurial has one.  Check it out [here](http://hginit.com/).

Version control systems aren't foolproof.  If its repository is also on the same computer you are working on, you run the risk of a disaster unless you have a backup.  If the repository is on another computer, you still need to have a backup strategy for it.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, yeah i guess i'll just have to move on..
and thanks for the TUT.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that worked for me in a similar situation.

Firstly the file was on my **LOCAL** drive and I lost the contents due to power failure.

I deleted that file from my local folder, then installed [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) (free software for undelete) and searched in that folder with Recuva. It was able to recover my file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, your advice worked fine with me. you deserve (1+).